# GG-plot 2 - legend is not matching

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I would like to plot several lines with gg-plot2 (Rstudio) and I would like to add a legend that matches the lines. So far it doesn't work. I do get a legend, but the names are not matching the colours of the lines. This is my script:

```
p5 <- ggplot(curve_JN1,aes(x=Exposure,y=LogRR,colour="red")) +
geom_line() +
geom_point(data=set,aes(x=exp,y=LogRR)) + 
scale_y_continuous("RR")+geom_errorbar(data=AML_set,aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper, x=exp),inherit.aes = F) + scale_x_continuous("Exposure")

p5 + geom_line(data=curve_JN2,aes(x=Exposure,y=LogRR, colour="black"))+
geom_line(data=curve_JN3,aes(x=Exposure,y=LogRR, colour="pink"))+
geom_line(data=curve_JN4,aes(x=Exposure,y=LogRR, colour="blue"))+
geom_line(data=curve_JN5,aes(x=Exposure,y=LogRR, colour="purple"))+
geom_line(data=curve_JN6,aes(x=Exposure,y=LogRR, colour="orange")) +
scale_color_discrete(name = "Studies", labels = c("Tracy", "Rick","Bart", "Audrey", "Belina", "Susan"))+
#scale_color_discrete(name = "Studies", labels = c("red", "black","pink", "blue", "purple", "orange"))+
theme(legend.position="right")
```

Comment: Use `color = "Tracy"` etc. inside the `aes` and use `scale_color_manual` to define specific colors. Usually, I'd use `scale_color_brewer` instead of manually defining colors as the scales from [Color Brewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=sequential&scheme=BuGn&n=3) are more aesthetic.

Comment: Hi Roland, thank you for your response. Unfortunately it still does not work: the references are not matching the colors (so e.g. Tracy is marked red in the legend but should be marked blue). I changed the color statement in aes (e.g. color = "tracy" , in stead of "blue"). And I added: scale_color_brewer (plaette= "Dark2"). Perhaps I should also define scale_color_brewer in more detail?

Comment: I suggest you start by studying the examples there: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html If you want specific colors, you need a manual scale.

Comment: Hi Roland, I am sorry, I just noticed that I tried your input again (using the references inside the aes statement, and defining colours with scale_color_manual), and it does work now. Thank you. The only thing is that the legend title is now: colour. I tried to do this: p5 + scale_fill_discrete(name = "New title") but that doesn't do the trick. Do you have any ideas on this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have to supply the name in scale_color_manual.